# What happened to NgRx npm package?

Tags: angular, npm-install, ngrx

I have a legacy project (Angular v. 4.3.6) which was not updated for a while (more than half a year).

Now when I run `npm install` it complains that `NgRx` package cannot be installed.
`"ngrx": "^2.0.0"` entry in `package.json` file.

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for ngrx@^2.0.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'code'
npm ERR! notarget
```

What should be used as a replacement for this dependency?

Comment: @bryan60 I updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngrx changed the way they distribute a while ago to be more modular and less monolithic.  You should probably just update your project cause 4 is very out of date at this point, but you'll want to change `ngrx` to `@ngrx/store` at a minimum, and possibly add some other dependencies depending on what you were using. not sure what ngrx was offering back then, but good candidates are `@ngrx/effects`, and `@ngrx/router-store`

you may also have to change your imports or possibly do a mapping in ts config?

docs: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/install

Comment: Ok, it looks like those who touched it previously did not bother to remove that dependency. Because @ngrx is referenced already.